# A method of MainActivity called from a Fragment or using a Singleton class, which is better for preventing memory leaks?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, admob

In my app I have a few `Fragments` and child `Fragments`. I need to call a method of the `MainActivity` from inside one of these `Fragments`. Which would be better practice to prevent memory leaks?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

....

public void interstitalAd() {
    clicksCount++;
    if (clicksCount % 3 == 0) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

and then in my `Fragment`

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
mainActivity.interstitialAd();
```

OR a Singleton class for my interstitial Ads?

```
public class Combine {

private static Combine instance;
private static Combine ourInstance = new Combine();
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private AdRequest adRequest;
private AtomicLong mIdGenerator = null;
private AtomicLong mIdGeneratorNews = null;

private Combine() {
}

private Combine(Context context) {
    mIdGenerator = new AtomicLong();
    mIdGeneratorNews = new AtomicLong();

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-21412412421/2324242");
    setupAds();
    requestNewInterstitial();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    });
}

public static Combine getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

public static Combine getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Combine(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public void go() {
    if (mIdGenerator.incrementAndGet() % 3 == 0) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}

public void goNews() {
    if (mIdGeneratorNews.incrementAndGet() % 2 == 0) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}

private void setupAds() {
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
}

}
```

and called from inside of any `Fragment` by

```
Combine.getInstance(getActivity()).go();
```

Comment: You could call your fragment's method from the activity it is attached, but not to call activity's method from fragment. A fragment is designed to be attached somewhere, inside an activity or event in a fragment. To active method from where it is attached, use callback design pattern, as the first answer suggest.

Comment: I did as the answer stated, however when the Screen ad pops up, the allocated memory reaches 24-34 mb and then after its closed it goes back to normal allocated memory

Comment: So it may be the popup's memory itself. Please use memory tracker in Android Studio for more detail. Every Fragment has an Activity instance, nevertheless you call it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recomended method to comunicate between `Fragments` and `Activities` is using `Listeners`. The point is to make mandatory for any activity that uses a concrete `Fragment` to implement it `Listener` with the methods it needs.

Here are an example of the implementation of the `Fragment` with a dummy `Listener`

```
public class LandingFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private LandingFragmentCallbacks mListener;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (LandingFragmentCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement LandingFragmentCallbacks");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * LandingFragmentCallbacks is an interface that all the activities that use {@link
     * me.upclose.aether.ui.fragments.LandingFragment} has to implement.         
     */
    public static interface LandingFragmentCallbacks {

        public void onRequestShowLoginFragment();

        public void onSkipLogin();
    }  
}
```

Take attetion to the onAttach and onDetach methods, they are called when the fragment is attached and detached. With that you are making mandatory, (and avoiding erros) to the activity to implement the Listener

Comment: I will give it a try on locking and unlocking DrawerLayout first before the InterstitialAd thing as its cross the whole app and update you

Comment: @JohnAndrew you can try in Android Studio to create a "Activity with Drawer" in an empty project and see the code that autogenerates. Or Create a new Fragment with the Android Studio interface, It creates with the Callback for you (and the other main tricks of fragment, the empty builder and the static method to instantiate the fragment

Comment: And, if the showInterstitialAd is something that is used in all the app you can create a BaseActivity and BaseFragment that make this (attach the BaseActivity that implements the BaseFragmentListener)

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Its working fine but well still whenever The interstitial ad pops up the allocated memory reaches 24~34 mb and when I close it, it goes back to the normal allocated memory

Comment: That is correct isn't it? Its normal that when the interstitial appear the memory increased and decreased after close it.

Comment: Yea I know but is it normal to double the memory? I tried with emulator of 16mb heap memory and it led to a crash after a few Ads poped and closed

Comment: With and interstitial? Yes i think is normal. Take attention that an interstitial normally is an image full screen sometimes animated. Bitmaps are heavy to load, and with a bigger screen with bigger resolution takes more and more memory. You can check where is allocated that memory but for sure is Admob, not your app

Comment: I will work on it and update you if I have any further inquiry, Thanks for the help :)